# Is it possible to copy all my bookmarks from Delicious to Evernote?

Tags: delicious, evernote

I'd like to migrate my content from Delicious from Evernote. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evernote used to offer this functionality, but they've since [discontinued it](https://support.evernote.com/link/portal/16051/16058/Article/2516/Can-I-import-my-Delicious-com-bookmarks-into-Evernote).

A third-party web application, [Delicious to Evernote](http://delicioustoevernote.rodrigojuarez.com.ar), now offers this functionality, but only imports 1000 bookmarks and sometimes errors with `Error processing : Exception of type 'Evernote.EDAM.Error.EDAMUserException' was thrown.` Also note that you need to trust this developer with your private information to use it.

Someone else offers [instructions on how to do this manually](http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.com/2010/12/import-delicious-bookmarks-to-evernote.html) using the Delicious API to export, a JavaScript-based translator, and the Evernote desktop app's import feature, but not everyone has been able to make this solution work for them.

For new bookmarks, it is possible to [replicate them on Evernote using ifttt.com](http://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=delicious%20evernote).

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this (unfortunate degredation of Delicious over the years forces it) and since several of the tools online no longer work, I found Evernicious, which is a Mac OSX solution and it worked great:

https://github.com/jorgemanrubia/evernicious/

You don't have to trust anyone with your bookmarks as in the other answer, as they never leave your machine.

This looks like another method but I wanted separate notes for my 1000+ delicious bookmarks:

http://joshgrenon.com/2010/02/14/the-simple-way-to-import-delicious-bookmarks-into-evernote/

Hope this helps!

-joe

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way, piecing together different parts of the puzzle.

Create a recipe using IFTTT, here's mine: https://ifttt.com/recipes/87796

Export your bookmarks from Delicious here: https://delicious.com/settings/sources

Then import the same exact .html file, in the same place on Delicious (link above).

When importing, make sure you add the tag "evernote".

Done!

Note: you'll create duplicates in Delicious, but I'm abandoning the account so I don't care.  Also, you could just then delete all notes with the tag "evernote" if you want.

Comment: Delicious disabled their import feature. http://export.delicious.com/settings/bookmarks/import now says "Bulk importing bookmarks from a flat file is currently not supported on Delicious.com.

We recommend looking into third-party providers using the Delicious API, such as IFTTT, Buffer, and many more, to import your links.". Unfortunately, that is what I got from the 'New' delicious in April 2014, because the 'Old' delicious is going away.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this solution succesfully. Follow the instructions in the link below
http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.com/2010/12/import-delicious-bookmarks-to-evernote.html

Make sure you read Windows specific workaround if you are on Windows. Also, if you have more than 1000 bookmarks append `?results=100000` to the delicious URL. [Delicious API docs](https://github.com/avos/delicious-api/blob/master/api/posts.md#v1postsall)

If you happen to get "invalid title" error, check your Evernote import file for empty `<title></title>` tags, and put something in.